# Connecting to the Python server script on the Raspberry Pi over the internet

Tags: python, networking, pi-zero

My application is simple, I want to create a Python server script on my Raspberry Pi and should be able to send a message to my server from internet.

My end goal is to control the Raspberry Pi GPIO depending on the message I receive through server.

If there's any alternate way to achieve this feel feel to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google for Python server you will get hundreds of thousands of hits.  Perhaps also add Raspberry Pi as a search term.

The [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) Python [module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) uses this method to control the Pi GPIO.

For a purer Python implementation perhaps also look at [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).